# Converted ASP.NET MVC 3 web site is not disaplaying new Razor riews

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have updates my ASP.NET 2010 MVC2 system to MVC3. I have also updated an in-progress MVC2 website to MVC3 using the conversion tool. I have left the current pages as .aspx including the master page. I have added a new .cshtml view. All the pages work except the new razor based view.

I get the following error

> The file "~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" could not be rendered, because it does not exist or is not a valid page.

It does exist because it displays the .aspx pages OK. How do I add the correct statement to display the .cshtml page in the

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="mainContent" runat="server">
```

I have tried

```
@RenderBody()
```

This gives the above error message. I have also tried

```
<%: RenderBody() %>
```

But this gives error

> The name "RenderBody" does not exist in the current context

The stack trace is as follows:

```
   [HttpException (0x80004005): The file "~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" could not be rendered, because it does not exist or is not a valid page.]
   System.Web.WebPages.Util.EnsureValidPageType(WebPageBase page, String virtualPath) +98735
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext() +166
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +95
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +220
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +115
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +303
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +23
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +260
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__1b() +19
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +177
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +343
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +116
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +37
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +60
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8841105
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can mix and match Razor pages and ASP.NET WebForms master pages.

See: [Is Razor view with ASPX .Master page possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479094/is-razor-view-with-aspx-master-page-possible)

*edit*: Well, not automatically.
http://eworldui.net/blog/post/2011/01/07/Using-Razor-Pages-with-WebForms-Master-Pages.aspx

Comment: Thanks for that. I thought I had checked all the previous questions but my search (MVC3 Razor) didn't display the question you are pointing to. I'll now have to think about whether I switch everything to .cshtml or carry on with .aspx pages?

Answer (score 0):

There are two files that are used to load the Razor equivalent of a master page in an ASP.NET MVC 3 Application Project, they are

_ViewStart.cshtml at the root of your project and the _Layout.cshtml file in the Views/Shared folder.  _Layout.cshtml is your masterpage.  The code

```
@RenderBody()
```

Is similar to the content place holder tags in a web forms master page.  You need to convert your master page to razor syntax and place the source code in _Layout.cshtml.  If you want to load a different layout view you would add the following code to your content view.

```
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Content Page";
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MyLayout.cshtml";
}
```

I hope this helps.