# ASP.net getting warning - The master page name is invalid because the name master page does not exist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I am using Visual Studio 2012. I am trying to create a view (asp.net) and i get the following error;

```
View Name: Index
View Engine : ASPX(C#)
create a strongly typed view [checked]
I have selected the model class
Scaffold template : List
Use a layout or master page: ~/Views/Shared/Site.Master
ContentPaceholder Id : content
```

The error/warning i get

> The master page name is invalid because the name master page does not exist.

How can i solve this ?

I found a similar question, but i don't understand the accepted solution . [Is Razor view with ASPX .Master page possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479094/is-razor-view-with-aspx-master-page-possible)

Note: It was a MVC application that i created.

Comment: I've never seen that error specifically.  Is that Verbatim the error message you are getting?

Comment: Yes it is `The master page name is invalid because the named master page does not exist.`

Comment: I found a similar question, but i don't understand the accepted solution . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479094/is-razor-view-with-aspx-master-page-possible

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem just now. Warning got vanished after moving master page to shared folder which is in view folder.